# ffmpeg video cropping "unable to parse option value "" as boolean"

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to crop .mp4 videos to a specific size using this code:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -filter:v "crop=900:1000:800:300” OUTPUT.mp4
```

However, even when I change the crop values, I get this error every time:

```
[crop @ 0x7f974e8441c0] Unable to parse option value "1000" as boolean
[crop @ 0x7f974e8441c0] Unable to parse option value "800" as boolean
[Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x7f974e8440c0] No option name near '300”'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f974e843dc0] Error initializing filter 'crop' with 
args '900:1000:800:300” out2.mp4
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf crop=900:1000:800:300”'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Comment: The second quote looks like the first one, but is different. Try replacing it with the ASCII quote: "

Comment: @GabrielDevillers that did it! Thanks!